# c# Signing xml document using stream

Tags: c#

I have encountered memory issue when using official method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures) to sign xml with large file, let says 600MB. Is there any way to sign xml using stream or others in c# to lower the usage of memory? I have found similar method to sign xml in stream in java but I can't implement it in c# since it involves too many classes. Thanks.